# When will the next chapter of 'Tales of Demons and Gods' be released?

Tags: tales-of-demons-and-gods

I have been reading [Tales of Demons and Gods](http://www.wuxiaworld.com/tdg-index/) for a week and just finished reading the published chapters.

I don't know when the next chapter will be released. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very hard for us to answer, but according to [this comment section](http://www.wuxiaworld.com/tdg-index/) the chapters are published at a rate of one per month.

> *"This one the chapters are being released monthly 1 per month to be exactly, because the author started to give more attention to the manga."*

The last several months, the chapter has been released around the 8th/10th, with some extra time for translation from the original Chinese.

Comment: Thankyou for the info....